# Using Scanner Class within a method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Tutorials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car Vehicle = new Car();
        Vehicle.supboys();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Car {
     private String Vehicle;
     public Car(String name) {
        Vehicle=name;
    }

Car() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");    
}
public void setName (String name) {
    Vehicle=name;
}
public String getName (){
    return Vehicle;
}
public void saying(){
    System.out.printf("Vehicle Brand is called %s\n ", getName());
}
public void supboys() {
    Scanner Boyz = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Your New Car is " + Boyz);
}
}
```

I am new to programming so I wanted to some practise, regarding constructors. I wanted to try doing a scanner class for this program but cant seem to get it to work. The program does not give a proper error message to me either. Does anyone have any suggestions? (Apologies for the messy code)

Comment: What outcome are you expecting and what is the output that you *do* get?

Comment: You are printing out the scanner instance itself. You should **use** the scanner class **methods** instead to retrieve data, e.g. `String line = Boyz.nextLine()`.

Comment: Your constructor looks fine... Are you having issues with the other methods?

Comment: Yeah the main problem is the method "public void supboys" even when i call it in my program it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Scanner's methods for Scanner to work the way you want. You would want to do something like this:

```
Scanner Boyz = new Scanner(System.in);
String shoutout = Boyz.nextLine();
System.out.println ("Your New Car is " + shoutout);
```